# unterminated address regex while using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to use the sed command to find and print the number that appears between "\MP2=" and "\" in a portion of a line that appears like this in a large .log file

```
\MP2=-193.0977448\
```

I am using the command below and getting the following error:

```
sed "/\MP2=/,/\/p" input.log
sed: -e expression #1, char 12: unterminated address regex
```

Advice on how to alter this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you just want to print lines that match a pattern use `grep`, not `sed`.

Answer (score 4):

Superficially, you just need to double up the backslashes (and it's generally best to use single quotes around the `sed` program):

```
sed '/\\MP2=/,/\\/p' input.log
```

Why?  The double-backslash is necessary to tell `sed` to look for one backslash.  The shell also interprets backslashes inside double quoted strings, which complicates things (you'd need to write 4 backslashes to ensure `sed` sees 2 and interprets it as 'look for 1 backslash') — using single quoted strings avoids that problem.

However, the `/pat1/,/pat2/` notation refers to two separate lines.  It looks like you really want:

```
sed -n '/\\MP2=.*\\/p' input.log
```

The `-n` suppresses the default printing (probably a good idea on the first alternative too), and the pattern looks for a single line containing `\MP2=` followed eventually by a backslash.

If you want to print just the number (as the question says), then you need to work a little harder.  You need to match everything on the line, but capture just the 'number' and remove everything except the number before printing what's left (which is just the number):

```
sed -n '/.*\\MP2=\([^\]*\)\\.*/ s//\1/p' input.log
```

You don't need the double backslash in the `[^\]` (negated) character class, though it does no harm.

Comment: This is because backslash is a regex metacharacter which is used for quoting. Because `/` is your regex separator, `\/` is required to match a regular slash in the pattern. Somewhat similarly, for consistency, `\,` matches a literal comma (only) even though this character doesn't have any special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

If the starting and ending pattern are on the same line, you need a substitution. The range expression `/r1/,/r2/` is true from (an entire) *line* which matches `r1`, through to the next entire line which matches `r2`.

You want this instead;

```
sed -n 's/.*\\MP2=\([^\\]*\)\\.*/\1/p' file
```

This extracts just the match, by replacing the entire line with just the match (the escaped parentheses create a group which you can refer back to in the substitution; this is called a back reference. Some `sed` dialects don't want backslashes before the grouping parentheses.)

Answer (score 0):

awk is a better tool for this:

```
awk -F= '$1=="MP2" {print $2}' RS='\' input.log
```

Set the record separator to \ and the field separator to '=', and it's pretty trivial.